# Apple warranty check script

Tags: php, json

After looking for some Ruby scripts i tried to write on PHP with some help the script.
My Problem is now that I am not sure if the jSon Objects are correct cause I dont know the source for it now.

My Question is if I am making anything wrong with jSon in PHP? If not than the Objects of the Sources are wrong.

```
<?php

$sn = isset($_GET['sn']) ? $_GET['sn'] : '';

if($sn)
{
    $url = 'https://selfsolve.apple.com/warrantyChecker.do?sn='.$sn . "&country=USA";

    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = substr($json, 5, -1);
    $json_obj = json_decode($json);

    if(isset($json_obj->ERROR_CODE))
    {
        echo $json_obj->ERROR_DESC;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "$json_obj->PROD_DESCR <img src=\"$json_obj->PROD_IMAGE_URL\" alt=\"\"><br>";

        echo"Product Description: $json_obj->PROD_DESCR <br>";
        echo"Purchase date: $json_obj->PURCHASE_DATE <br>";
        echo"Warranty exp date: $json_obj->COVERAGE_DATE <br>";

    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <p><input name="sn" value="<?=$sn?>"><input type="submit" value="Lookup serial"></p>
</form>
```

Another way I have tried to do it is

```
<?php 
$sn = $argv[1]; 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents( 
       "https://selfsolve.apple.com/warrantyChecker.do?sn=". $sn . "&country=USA"));
echo "Product Description" .$data->PROD_DESCR."\n";
echo "Coverage for " . $sn . " ends on " . $data->COVERAGE_DATE . "\n"; 
?>
```

Comment: "I dont know the source for it now." what do you mean?

Comment: try getting the response from target url through curl .. and also donot use substring before json decode ..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$sn = isset($_GET['sn']) ? $_GET['sn'] : '';

if($sn)
{
    $url = 'https://selfsolve.apple.com/warrantyChecker.do?sn='.$sn . "&country=USA";

    $json = file_get_contents($url);

    //This line you are splitting the json form then it wont work
    $json = substr($json, 5, -1);

    $json_obj = json_decode($json);

    if(isset($json_obj->ERROR_CODE))
    {
        echo $json_obj->ERROR_DESC;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "$json_obj->PROD_DESCR <img src=\"$json_obj->PROD_IMAGE_URL\" alt=\"\"><br>";

        echo"Product Description: $json_obj->PROD_DESCR <br>";

        echo"Purchase date: $json_obj->PURCHASE_DATE <br>";

        echo"Warranty exp date: $json_obj->COVERAGE_DATE <br>";


    }
}
?>
```